# Getting confused while padding number into integer number

Tags: java

Using `String.format`

- If I use `%5`  I get output with space as output 1.
- If I use `%05` I get output as output 2.

Why is output 1 printing space instead of padding number?

```
 Output 1 ::    12 (String str = String.format("%5d", 12);)
 Output 2 :: 00012 (String str = String.format("%05d", 12);)
```

Output 2 is correct. But my question is what is need to '0' with '%'?

Comment: Have you check the documentation ?

Comment: maybe your application needs a number with 5 digits, padded with zero... e.g. a number to be scanned (hand scanner)

Comment: My Question is why its printing space instead of number while I have used '%5d'?

Comment: Because you ask to have a numeric with a width of 5. If the value is smaller (in length), it add spaces. Remove the 5 if you don't want a specific length. If you want a padding with '0', you add the flag '0' after '%'. Everything is explained in the `Formatter` documentation, see my answer for the link

Answer (score 1):

As the [`String.format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) redirect to the [`Formatter page`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax), you can found the syntax about numeric, more important, the flags :

> Flags
>
> '0'    -   Requires the output to be padded with leading zeros to the minimum field width following any sign or radix indicator except when converting NaN or infinity. If the width is not provided, then a MissingFormatWidthException will be thrown. 
>       ...

This explained why you have leading '0'

Then, you have default style saying that if you don't specify it,

> The output is right-justified within the width

So it use space the right-justified by default, or '0' if you ask leading 0.

Comment: If I need to add and character the how can we add?

Comment: @ShiladittyaChakraborty define your problem ... you want to pad the number with other character than '0' ? I would do it the simplest way (since I don't remember reading anything about a flag that would help you) with `String.format("%5d", 12).replace(" ", "#");` to pad with "#"